# Find all regex matches of different extensions

Tags: regex

I have the following statement:

```
<div><img src="pict001.png"></div><div><img src="pict002.jpg"></div>
```

I'm trying to get a match of the src names, so that the result is:

```
 [ "pict001.png", "pict002.jpg" ]
```

So far I have:

```
/pict[\d]+\.wpf/
```

but I’m having trouble with the or (|) on the file extension

Comment: _all_ extensions? I'd say `\.[^.]+`, unless you care to narrow it down.

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of accepted file extensions you can set it up like this:
`pict[\d]+\.(jpg|png|xyz)`.  What you do is surround the different types of extensions you expect in `()` with `|` dividing them.  [Using your test data you provided I did some quick testing on Rubular.](http://rubular.com/r/IFoYamFdmq)

If you don't have a list of extensions you can do something a little more dynamic like: `pict[\d]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`.  This is pretty much the same thing, only it will return any file extensions that are 2 to 3 chars. long.  By tweaking the numbers you can allow any odd extension in a certain range of chars.

With more complex regex, it helps to break them into smaller pieces to figure out all the rules.  In this situation you can take the `pict[\d]+\.` part which you already have to match against `pict#######.`.  After that you just need a smaller regex to tack on the end to find your extensions.  You can make this as complicated (or simple) as needed.  Looking at the two I provided, the only real difference comes after `pict[\d]+\.`, so that is where you can customize it with extra rules and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for all matches of this would work:

```
pict[\d]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$))
```

If you want specific extensions, you can replace the [a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)) with (png|jpg|gz) or something, but an extension can be any combination of numbers and letters.